# How to redirect twice in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have added flash message on page using connect-flash.

For displaying flash message, I have redirected page to same page with following code

```
 req.flash('success', 'Password Changed successfully, you will be logout after 10 seconds');
 return res.redirect('/user/changepwd');
```

by this way, I can show flash message on the page. but after that I want user to auto logout and redirect to homepage.

How can I achieve that ? can we redirect twice with some setTimeout() ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should redirect from UI, after receiving the message of Success from express.

Comment: I expect that logout operation to redirect automate to the home page.

Comment: Hi @MihaiCatan, yes, from logout , I am redirecting user to login page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of Mihai's comment, redirect user from UI. i.e. ejs file as below.

```
<% if (sucessMessage) { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.location.href = "/logout";
  }, 10000);
</script>
<% } %>
```

with this code, if I get successMessage, then redirecting to logout page.
and at express application, I have clear all cookies and sessions and then redirect it to login page again.

added one route for logout as below

```
router.get('/logout', userController.getLogout);
```

then added its controller function

```
  exports.getLogout = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.clearCookie("user_sid");
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```